# Angularjs ng-repeat creating inconsistent spacing between list elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've encountered a problem with `ng-repeat` because I'm not getting constistent spacing between list elements. For example, I've declared the following `css`...

```
.test-grid {}

.test-grid ul {
    list-style: none;    
}

.test-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: red;    
}
```

...using `display: inline-block` so I can create a list that spans one line. Now I write the following `html`...

```
<div class="test-grid">
  <ul>
     <li>{{ctrl.items[0]}}</li>
     <li>{{ctrl.items[1]}}</li> 
     <li>{{ctrl.items[2]}}</li>            
  </ul>
</div>
```

Which produces the output shown in 1, where there is a gap between 'tom', 'jerry' and 'pluto'...

[image: screenshot]

If I use `ng-repeat` now, like so...

```
<div class="test-grid">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="$item in ctrl.items">
            {{$item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I get the output shown in 2 where there is now no space between 'tom', 'jerry' and 'pluto'. If I should move the `ng-repeat` to the `<ul>` element, like so...

```
<div class="test-grid">
    <ul ng-repeat="$item in ctrl.items">
        <li>
            {{$item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I get the output shown in 3 above, where the list items are on separate lines and for some reason the `css` formatting has been lost. I dont' know why but I think the reason for the gap in 1 is because there is whitespace between the list elements, for example... `<li>item<\li> <li>` instead of `<li>item<\li><li>`. And I'm guessing this has been removed by `ng-repeat`.

Which is the correct way to use the `ng-repeat` here? And is there a fix that will produce consistent spacing whether `ng-repeat` is used or not? Ideally I'd prefer no spacing between list elements.

Note, I'm writing a library of html widgets and I don't know if the user will write the html using `ng-repeat` or without but I need the result to be the same either way. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kergoog/o8aabqqv/2/) of the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1 and 2 are both correct. As you said, the spacing results from the formatting in your html combined with "display: inline-block". If you put all three li-items on one line, you won't have the spacing anymore.

Version 3 is not correct, because instead of creating a list with 3 elements, it creates 3 lists with 1 element each.

To achieve consistent results between version 1 and 2, you could use the following css:

```
.test-grid {
}

.test-grid ul {
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;
}

.test-grid li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: red;    
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! So instead of `inline block` we can set the `li` to be a block element, then `float: left` to place the next `li` element on the same line with no space. I get that `clear: both` in the `ul` stops elements being placed either side of the list, but do you know why this is needed here? It looks like you're setting the `li` elements to float and not the `ul` but that's not the case?